# I want to implement a spring cron scheduler that should run for the 1st time when the application is started and run every 1 hour from the next time

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron, scheduler

Eg. if I am starting the application at 9.10 am then it should run 1st time on 9.10 am and from the next time it should run in every 1 hour like at 10.10 am, 11.10 am, 12.10 pm etc

Note : This is a springboot application

Comment: Take a look at https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

Comment: How would it run for the first tim at 9.10 if you start it at 12.10?

Comment: sorry, I updated the question it should run immediately after starting the application

Comment: https://crontab.guru/examples.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start it manually (from code) first time when the application has finished startup and then use scheduler to run it every hour using [@Scheduled annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html).

Examples for `@Scheduled` annotation:

- [Baeldung on @Scheduled annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks)
- [Callicoder and their "How to Schedule Tasks with Spring Boot"](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-task-scheduling-with-scheduled-annotation/)

Note:
I think `@Scheduled(fixedRate = 3600000)` (where `3600000` is 60 minutes in milliseconds, i.e. each hour) is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: But I want to do this using cron expression, because my scheduler time may change in future

Comment: @Scheduled do also support cron type scheduling, like for example:
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 12 * * MON,THU") // at 12:00 on Monday and Thursday